# Expected Value Brownian Motion

Tags: probability

I'm pretty bad at maths, I'm studying economics but I have this question that I can't solve.
W is a brownian motion.
Compute : Ep[Ws².Wt²] . Ep being the expected value.
My problem is that I know nothing about the properties of brownian motion. The teacher did not explain us much things...
I wanted to do the following things.
Ep[Ws².Wt²]=Ep[Ws²+Wt²-Wt²,Wt²]=Ep[Ws²-wt²,Ws²-Wo²]+Ep[Wt²,Wt²]
I just know that Ep[Wt,Wt]=Wt but I know nothing else.
Could you help me ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does the comma inside the expectation stand for? Conditional expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t <s$. Then $EW_s^{2}W_t^{2}=E((W_s-W_t)+W_t)^{2}W_t^{2}$. Expanding the square we get $E((W_s-W_t)^{2}W_t^{2}+EW_t^{4}+2E(W_s-W_t)W_t^{3}$. Now you need the fact that $W_s-W_t$ and $W_t$ are in dependent. Hence above quantity becomes $E((W_s-W_t)^{2}EW_t^{2}+EW_t^{4}+2E(W_s-W_t)EW_t^{3}$. The last term  is $0$ because $E(W_s-W_t)=EW_s-EW_t=0-0=0$. You also need the fact that $W_s-W_t$ has normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $s-t$. We get $W_s^{2}W_t^{2}=(s-t)t+EW_t^{4}$. We  can write this as $(s-t)t+ct^{2}$ where $c$ is the fourth moment of standard normal distribution. The value of $c$ is $3$.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks